# AngularJS throws Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope error when I try to use modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have just started with AngularJS
The following code gives an error in the console.

Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- newActiveOrdersModel . I have researched but it looks like Unknown Provider error can happen for a variety of reasons.It would be nice if anyone could point out where I am going wrong ?

```
var app;
(function(angular){

    app = angular.module('OrdersDashboard',[]);
    app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/current/new', {templateUrl: 'orders/partials/new_current', controller: 'newActiveOrdersCtrl'}).
            otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }]);
    app.service('newActiveOrdersModel', ['$scope', '$rootScope',
        function($scope, $rootScope){

            this.Orders=["This is a test order"];
            this.fetchOrders = function(){

                console.log("This is a test order");
                this.Orders=["This is a test order1111"];
            };
        }]);
    app.controller('newActiveOrdersCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'newActiveOrdersModel',
        function($scope, $rootScope, newActiveOrdersModel){

            $scope.test="Hello World";
        }]);

})(angular);
```

It seems like Angular Js cannot recognize "newActiveOrdersModel".

Comment: You can't inject `$scope` into services, there is nothing like a singleton $scope. Not sure why you are trying to inject it as your code doesn't seem to be making any use of it...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This just a guess but I don't know why you have $scope listed as a dependency of your service. I think something like this

```
 app.service('newActiveOrdersModel', ['$rootScope',
    function($rootScope){..}]
```

will solve the error. Also I wouldn't include $rootScope unless you absolutely need it. It's generally considered bad practice in Angular to store stuff in the $rootScope.

Comment: I didn't know that scope cannot be listed as a dependency.RootScope will be required as I intend to fire events for communicating with models

Comment: Ok, well sometimes you just have to use the rootScope but I would recommend storing your events in another service instead of using the global scope. Again, nothing inherently wrong with using the global scope but it's considered better practice not too in order to prevent naming conflicts and overpopulating the global scope.