# angular services declaration

Tags: angularjs, web-services

I am working on a simple angular SPA. I got the services working, and then wanted to extract them to a separate file. I've done something wrong with syntax and dependencies, and I'm wondering if anyone can help me spot it. I know I am confusing some things, and there might be a couple of additional bugs. I'm open to hearing some ideas about where I'm going wrong here. Please advise.

[current angular error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=)

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- FetchProduct
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/unpr?p0=<article class="demo ng-scope" ng-view="product-list">copeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20FetchProduct
```

> Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider Unknown provider:  Description
>   This error results from the $injector being unable to resolve a
>   required dependency. To fix this, make sure the dependency is defined
>   and spelled correctly.

**markup**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
  <title>Kat Chilton | Escalada | Angular Skills Demo App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css" type="text/css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ProductListCtrl">
  <article class="demo" ng-view="product-list">
  </article>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="services.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', [
'ngRoute',
'DemoControllers',
'DemoServices'
]);

demoApp.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/products/', {
        templateUrl: 'product-list.html',
        controller: 'ProductListCtrl'
    })
    .when('/products/:product_id', {
        templateUrl: 'product-detail.html',
        controller: 'ProductDetailCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/products/'
    });
}]);
```

**controllers.js**

```
var DemoControllers = angular.module('DemoControllers', []);

DemoControllers.controller('ProductListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'FetchList',
function ($scope, $http, FetchList) {
    $scope.products = FetchList;
}]);

DemoControllers.controller('ProductDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', 'FetchProduct',
function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, FetchProduct) {
    $scope.selection = FetchProduct;
}]);
```

**services.js**:

```
var DemoServices = angular.module('DemoServices', []);

DemoServices.factory('FetchList', ['$http', function ($http) {
var list;
var FetchList = function ($http) {
    $http.get('https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/developer-application-test/cart/list')
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // console.log('data :: ', data, 'status :: ', status, 'headers :: ', headers, 'config :: ', config);
            list = data.products;
    });
};
return {products: new FetchList($http)};
}]);

DemoServices.factory('FetchProduct', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
    var product;
var FetchProduct = function ($http, $scope) {
    $http.get('https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/developer-application-test/cart/' + $scope.product_id + '/detail')
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('data :: ', data, 'status :: ', status, 'headers :: ', headers, 'config :: ', config);
        product = data;
    });
};

return {product: new FetchProduct($http, $scope)};
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'DemoControllers'
])
.service('DemoServices');
```

This is incorrect. The [`service()` method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#service) is used to add a new service to the module. It takes a service name as argument, and a constructor function for the service. What 'DemoServices' is here is the name of a module. And you want to add this module as a dependency of demoApp. So you just need to add it to the dependencies array, already containing ngRoute and DemoControllers:

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'DemoControllers',
    'DemoServices'
]);
```

EDIT:

OK, now that I have a clear error message, the error is more obvious. Your service FetchProduct depends on `$scope`. But `$scope` is not a service, and thus can't be injected in a service. Controllers have a $scope, and angular creates one every time the controller is instantiated, but services are singletons, and don't have any scope: they're not associated to any DOM element.

Your service should look like this:

```
DemoServices.factory('productFetcher', ['$http', function($http) {

    var getProduct = function(productId) {
        return $http.get('https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/developer-application-test/cart/' + productId + '/detail').then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    });

    return {
        getProduct: getProduct;
    };
}]);
```

and it should be used like this, in a controller, to get the product 42:

```
productFetcher.getProduct(42).then(function(product) {
    $scope.product = product;
});
```

Comment: I made this suggested change. The error is still occurring. I have added the error to the original question, and will update the post to reflect your change.

Comment: Make sure to post the error message you actually get. Not the generic description of the error type. We need to know **which** provider can't be found.

Comment: Added. It's erroring out on FetchProduct, no matter which view I check.

Comment: Have you added a script for services.js file to your index.html page? Also, the posted error message looks really strange. Why is there html markup in the middle of the error message?

Comment: updated with the markup. I was wondering about the markup in the error, too.

Comment: You should not use the minified version of angular during development. Use the non-minified version, and you'll get much clearer error messages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75644/discussion-between-kraken-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546032/angularjs-throws-unknown-provider-scopeprovider-scope-error-when-i-try-to - I think this is because I'm trying to inject scope. How do I pass the parameter to the service?

Comment: You remove the two useless parameters of FetchProduct, and add a parameter productId instead. And you return `{product: FetchProduct}`instead of calling the function when returning the service, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I don't see where to pass the parameter into the service.

Comment: ok, well I guess that at least gives me the solution. I'll post another question if I can't find it. Thanks!