# AngularJS: Throws Unknown Provider error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have looked over many threads of this error, yet following the instructions on 2 of them, it still throws the same error, here is my service:

```
angular.module('sccateringApp')
  .service('httpcalls', function ($scope, $http) {
      var BackEndBaseURL = "methods/server.php";
      return {
          ..
      }
  });
```

And here is my controller:

```
angular.module('sccateringApp')
  .controller('newCategoryController', ['httpcalls', '$scope', function (httpcalls, $scope) {

      $scope.submitForm = function(){
        alert();
      }

  }]);
```

I can't really identify what the problem is, since I already included the service per se as a dependency of the controller. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Only controllers have access to `$scope`. Remove it from your `httpcalls` service. Also, in future, add any error messages to your question

Comment: I'm sorry I'm relatively new to Angular, if you post this as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct one. Thanks! I knew it was something simple that was causing the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS throws Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope error when I try to use modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546032/angularjs-throws-unknown-provider-scopeprovider-scope-error-when-i-try-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update: Phil is right, the real provider error comes from the dependency on `$scope`, credits to him when he post it.*

---

It looks like you are creating a factory and not a service.

You don't need to return anything from a service, but declare things in the `this` (it is a prototype instanciation, like a class).

```
sccateringApp.service('httpcalls', function ($scope, $http) {
  var BackEndBaseURL = "methods/server.php";

  this.someMethod = function() { ... }
  this.someProperty = ...
});
```

Otherwise, just replace `module.service` by `module.factory`